# read data from a file while ignoring non alphabetic chars and storing the variable to be inserted into a trie

Tags: c

I'm basically trying to read data from a file while ignoring all non alphabetic characters and any characters preceding a non alphabetic would be considered the end of the word and should be inserted into a trie. any ideas?
Heres my current code which is getting a seg fault

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 char input;

void readDict(FILE *dict_file)
{
    int line = 0;
    char curr;

    while ( (curr = fgetc(dict_file))!= EOF)
    {
        if(isalpha(curr))
        {
            strcpy(input,curr);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
            printf("invalid input");
    else
    {
        FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        readDict(pFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26289719/971127

Comment: read it, not sure what to do.

Comment: _getting a seg fault_  `strcpy(input,curr);`

Comment: yes, i know. What should i use instead to store the input from the file?

Comment: The read one more time.

Comment: Also: `char curr;` should be `int curr;` to distinguish `EOF` from the other 256 `char`.

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault is being generated by `strcpy`. You must pass `char *` to `strcpy` as arguments. In the code you posted, both `input` and `curr` are of `char` type.

Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/ to understand how to use `strcpy`.